# Can't open port with ufw

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, ufw, nmap

I need to open the port `8081` for my application. I want to connect to the application from another server. Problem I can't open the port. 
I started the application with port 8081 and ip 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1
,I enabled ufw /disabled ufw, I read the tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-20-04

my system:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu D

description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Release:    20.04

Codename:   focal

Output of `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`:

app 4431          foo   27u  IPv4  64011      0t0  TCP *:8081 (LISTEN)

output of `sudo ufw status`

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8081/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8081                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8081/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8081 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

nmap output:

Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-06-09 21:03 UTC
Nmap scan report for myip.bc.googleusercontent.com (myip)
Host is up (0.00062s latency).
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.19 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a google cloud compute instance, your instance probably has a VPC with its own default firewall rules:

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls

> The **default network** is pre-populated with firewall rules that allow incoming connections to instances. These rules can be deleted or modified as necessary:
>
> **default-allow-internal**
> Allows ingress connections for all protocols and ports among instances in the network. This rule has the second-to-lowest priority of 65534, and it effectively permits incoming connections to VM instances from others in the same network.
>
> **default-allow-ssh**
> Allows ingress connections on TCP port 22 from any source to any instance in the network. This rule has a priority of 65534.
>
> **default-allow-rdp**
> Allows ingress connections on TCP port 3389 from any source to any instance in the network. This rule has a priority of 65534, and it enables connections to instances running the Microsoft Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP).
>
> **default-allow-icmp**
> Allows ingress ICMP traffic from any source to any instance in the network. This rule has a priority of 65534, and it enables tools such as ping

so the default rules don't include port 8081 from anywhere...

You can create a new fireall rule to allow ingress to 8081 on the Google cloud platform web console (VPC network -> Firewall) using this doc:

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules

It would look like this

[image]

## Also

nmap is a bit slow, so you might want to try connecting directly with either telnet or nc:

```
$ telnet myip.bc.googleusercontent.com 8081
Trying 123.123.123.123...
Connected to myip.bc.googleusercontent.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
```

or

```
$ nc -zv myip.bc.googleusercontent.com 8081
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 123.123.123.123:1234.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.24 seconds.
```

Comment: nc -zv myip
Connection to myip port [tcp/ssh] succeeded! 8081 no connection.